# Extras in LocalePicker intent

Tags: android-intent, locale

I am trying to call up com.android.settings/.LocalePicker via adb shell for inclusion in a Tasker app.

When I do

```
am start -n com.android.settings/.LocalePicker
```

I see only the current system Language locale and none of the other device options.

If, instead, I proceed through the hidden Development Settings menu which has Locale as an option, then I get the full interactive screen of languages/locales from which to make a selection.

I should point out that this is on an Android 2.1 system, so many more modern options are unavailable. This is a portion of the logcat from selecting Locale from the hidden Development Settings menu:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1111): Starting activity: Intent {     
act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.LocalePicker   
(has extras) }
D/ResourceType( 1162): calling getConfigurations
D/ResourceType( 1162): called getConfigurations size=68
D/asset   ( 1162): locale  0: ''
D/asset   ( 1162): locale  1: 'de'
D/asset   ( 1162): locale  2: 'fr'
D/asset   ( 1162): locale  3: 'es'
D/asset   ( 1162): locale  4: 'it'
D/asset   ( 1162): locale  5: 'en_GB'
D/asset   ( 1162): locale  6: 'en_US'
D/asset   ( 1162): locale  7: 'zh_TW'
D/asset   ( 1162): locale  8: 'fr_CA'
D/asset   ( 1162): locale  9: 'de_DE'
D/asset   ( 1162): locale 10: 'fr_FR'
D/asset   ( 1162): locale 11: 'es_ES'
D/asset   ( 1162): locale 12: 'it_IT'
D/asset   ( 1162): locale 13: 'en'
D/asset   ( 1162): locale 14: 'zh'
```

The "has extras" is not illuminating in the way that I had hoped. I've researched this with my limited understanding and recognize there is some additional information being sent when the menu option is accessed as opposed to just sending the intent via ADB. But I have no idea what form or format that information would take. I've decompiled the Settings app and had a look at the Manifest as well as the smali files for Locale, but my understanding of Java is very limited.

Is there something else I should be looking at?

Oh, and the Tasker Misc>Settings Dialog>Locale Settings also just brings up the current set Locale, not the interactive list.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the needed extras in res\xml\settings_development.xml of the decompiled Settings.apk:

```
<extra android:name="hideDevLanguages" android:value="false" />
```

Thus a working command line in adb shell is:

```
am start -n com.android.settings/.LocalePicker --ez hideDevLanguages false
```